# Multiple splits in pandas string

Tags: python, pandas

## splitting the reviews_list feature into two features

```
name            reviews_list
Jalsa           [('Rated 4.0', 'RATED\n A beautiful place to ...
Spice Elephant  [('Rated 4.0', 'RATED\n Had been here for din...
San Churro Cafe [('Rated 3.0', "RATED\n Ambience is not that ...
```

Above is the `head()` of my dataframe with 2 features `name` and `reviews_list`. I want to split the feature `reviews_list` into two features :

1. Have only the ratings (4.0, 3.0)
2. only the reviews from customers i.e.(A beautiful place to ... , Had been here for din..., Ambience is not that ...)
3. delete : [('Rated ,  'RATED\n

Comment: can you print your df.head() and add it to your question?

Comment: @Sangeetha S A can you give an example of imput data before your code? You can simply copy and paste it and use the Code Sample {} feature in the beginning on your question. Also, a little bit more desired  ouput data would be helpful.

Comment: or how can i delete every thing on left side of the the string(long review from customer). i just need the review "Had been here for dinner...."  [('Rated 4.0', 'RATED\n Had been here for din...

Answer (score 0):

From your sample, it seems as if you have a CSV in your `reviews_list` column. So, something akin to this should work, assuming you've read your data into the DataFrame called `frame`:

```
import csv
RATED_INDEX, TEXT_INDEX = 0, 1

reader = csv.reader(frame.reviews_list.values) 
next(reader)
good_list = [[float(r[RATED_INDEX].split(' ')[1]), '\n'.join(r[TEXT_INDEX].split('\n')[1:])] for r in reader]
```

It works for what you've shown.